# How to replace all underscores in a text except the ones that are part of a specific word or pattern in Unix Shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file that contains lot of underscores and i have to replace all of them with empty string except the ones that are part of a specific string usr_mstr.
I have tried sed command, it replaces underscore and excludes the words i provided, but it also replaces the character immediately following underscore! Any help will greatly be appreciated..

```
echo "fname_sname_id_usr_mstr" | sed 's/_[^usr_mstr]//g'
```

Expected output:

```
fnamesnameidusr_mstr
```

Actual Output:

```
fnamenamedusr_mstr
```

(`s` and `i` got replaced)

Comment: For what it's worth, your script doesn't work on Mac OS at all.  It produces `fname_snamed_usr_mstr`.

Comment: Was using bash shell.... Thanks for the response

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(usr_mstr)|_/\1/g' file
```

Globally replace `usr_mstr` by itsself or replace `_` by nothing

Comment: Clever.  Note that on some systems it's `-E` instead of `-r`.

Comment: The point made by @JohnZwinck  is makes the solution extra portable as `-E` is recognized in almost all sed versions in use today.

Answer (score 5):

`[^usr_mstr]` is a character class that matches any character that's not `u`, `s`, `r`, `m`, `t`, or `_`.

Perl supports "look-around" assertions, so you can write:

```
echo "fname_sname_id_usr_mstr_x_usr_other_mstr_y_usrmstr_z" \
| perl -pe 's/(?<!usr)_//g;s/_(?!mstr)//g'
```

i.e. replace _ if not preceded by `usr`, and not followed by `mstr`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i exclude a string as such when using sed.. More like telling to sed, Hey buddy, you match all underscores but exclude those words i listed out...

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. sed doesn't support look-arounds.

Comment: Okay... One question though, does negative look around work for a string rather than a character. Say i need to match when "albert" is not followed by "einstein".

Comment: @JosePaul: In the example, it works for words "usr" and "mstr". I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to replace word "albert" in a text file that is immediately not followed by word  "einstein".. I need a reg ex that matches whole word instead of matching individual characters like character classes do....

Comment: @JosePaul: My answer doesn't use any character classes.

Comment: Yes... That helped me to understand my mistake...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this with standard sed BRE regex alone. With `sed` you would basically need to replace "usr_mstr" with a placeholder string, then replace all the underscores and then replace the placeholder string with the "usr_master" ..

```
echo "fname_sname_id_usr_mstr" |
{ null="@#@"; sed "s/usr_mstr/$null/g; s/_//g; s/$null/usr_mstr/g" ;}
```

An alternative is to try awk :

```
echo "fname_sname_id_usr_mstr" |
awk -v s="usr_mstr" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=s} {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub("_","",$i)}1'
```

Which should work as long a `s` does not contains regular characters that are special in extended regular expressions.